# Pandas: Extracting List-Dictionary column into separate columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I have this dataframe df.

| tweet_id | tweet_entites |
| --- | --- |
| 1223395611921305601 | [{'label': 'NORP', 'term': 'Chinese'}, {'label': 'ORG', 'term': 'InnoCare'}, {'label': 'GPE', 'term': 'Hong Kong'}] |
| 1223395868092465153 | NaN |
| 1223396204093902849 | [{'label': 'ORG', 'term': 'LIVE Press'}, {'label': 'ORG', 'term': 'Emergency Committee'}] |
| 1223396269655089154 | [{'label': 'CARDINAL', 'term': '83'}, {'label': 'CARDINAL', 'term': '2019nCoV'}, {'label': 'CARDINAL', 'term': '83'}] |

I want to extract the list-dictionary into separate columns as such:

| tweet_id | label | term |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1223395611921305601 | NORP | Chinese |
| 1223395611921305601 | ORG | InnoCare |
| 1223395611921305601 | GPE | Hong Kong |
| 1223395868092465153 | NaN | NaN |
| 1223396204093902849 | ORG | LIVE Press |
| 1223396204093902849 | ORG | Emergency Committee |
| 1223396269655089154 | CARDINAL | 83 |
| 1223396269655089154 | CARDINAL | 2019nCoV |
| 1223396269655089154 | CARDINAL | 83 |

The new columns will be named as label and term. I've seen references but I haven't been able to find one that is similar to the output that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are already lists of dicts use nested list comprehension with replace misisng values:

```
zipped = zip(df['tweet_id'], 
             df['tweet_entites'].apply(lambda x: [{'label':np.nan}] 
                                                 if isinstance(x, float) 
                                                 else x))

df = [{**{'tweet_id': x}, **z} for x, y in zipped for z in y]

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print (df)
              tweet_id     label                 term
0  1223395611921305601      NORP              Chinese
1  1223395611921305601       ORG             InnoCare
2  1223395611921305601       GPE            Hong Kong
3  1223395868092465153       NaN                  NaN
4  1223396204093902849       ORG           LIVE Press
5  1223396204093902849       ORG  Emergency Committee
6  1223396269655089154  CARDINAL                   83
7  1223396269655089154  CARDINAL             2019nCoV
8  1223396269655089154  CARDINAL                   83
```

If there are strings repr of list use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

df['tweet_entites'] = df['tweet_entites'].fillna('[{"label":None}]').apply(ast.literal_eval)


zipped = zip(df['tweet_id'], df['tweet_entites'])

df = [{**{'tweet_id': x}, **z} for x, y in zipped for z in y]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print (df)
              tweet_id     label                 term
0  1223395611921305601      NORP              Chinese
1  1223395611921305601       ORG             InnoCare
2  1223395611921305601       GPE            Hong Kong
3  1223395868092465153      None                  NaN
4  1223396204093902849       ORG           LIVE Press
5  1223396204093902849       ORG  Emergency Committee
6  1223396269655089154  CARDINAL                   83
7  1223396269655089154  CARDINAL             2019nCoV
8  1223396269655089154  CARDINAL                   83
```

Answer (score 0):

**if df['tweet_entites'] is a string then you can use eval to convert it into list:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = df.fillna("[{'label': None, 'term': None}, {'label': None, 'term': None}, {'label': None, 'term': None}]")

frames = []
for row in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
  for i in eval(row["tweet_entites"]):
    i["tweet_id"] = int(row["tweet_id"])
    frames.append(i)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(frames)
print(new_df)
```